# Generating Function of Integer Partitions

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Let $p_{k}(n)$ be a number of partitions of $n$ that into parts not greater than  $k$.

$p_{k}(n)=p_{k-1}(n)+p_{k}(n-k)$

i will prove this partition recurrence bu using Generating Functions of Integer partitions. In fact i have an idea but i am not sure whether it is true or not.we can see that;

$$
P(\leq k)=P(=k)+P(\leq k-1)
$$
So we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{1}{(1-q)\left(1-q^{2}\right)\dots\left(1-q^{k}\right)}=\frac{q^{k}}{(1-q)\left(1-q^{2}\right)\dots\left(1-q^{k}\right)}\\
&+\frac{1}{(1-q)\left(1-q^{2}\right)\dots\left(1-q^{k-1}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Since this equality is provided,this proof is completed.i dont know my opinion is right or not?can anyone help please? Have i any mistake?

We can also think any different solutions? Maybe from bijective proof and ferrers diagrams?i am also open and another solutions.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument seems OK but might be more complicated than necessary.  You can instead derive the recurrence from first principles by conditioning on whether a partition contains a part of size $k$ or not.  If it does, then removing $k$ yields a partition of $n-k$ into parts $\le k$.  If it doesn't, then you have a partition of $n$ into parts $\le k-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i want to ask a question.Can we use this formula to solve this question?                                             
$$
p_{k}(n)=\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1-q^{(k+1) J}}{1-q^{J}}
$$

Comment: Not quite, but this is correct: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_k(n)q^n=\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{1-q^j}$$

Comment: ok i understand. i am new in this topic .i am learning and searching about it. thanks for your supports:)

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark the answer accepted.